# How can I streaming my web camera to users on the site with signalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr, video-streaming, webrtc, broadcast

How can I streaming my web camera to users on the site  with signalR ?
Via the following code move the writing and whiteborad

```
 [HubName("whiteboardHub")]
public class WhiteboardHub : Hub
{
    public void JoinGroup( string groupName)
    {

         Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);


    }
    public void JoinChat(string name, string groupName)
    {


        Clients.Group(groupName).ChatJoined(name);

    }

    public void SendDraw(string drawObject, string sessionId, string groupName,string name)
    {
        Clients.Group(groupName).HandleDraw(drawObject, sessionId, name);
    }

    public void SendChat( string message, string groupName,string name)
    {
        Clients.Group(groupName).Chat(name, message);
    }


}
```

What is the idea of ​​transferring my webcam to existing users?
My project idea is virtual classroom
So I want to streaming  voice and video from the teacher to the students